# Problem in solving a question related to real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis

**The question is** :

Does there exist a non-negative continuous function $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} f^{n} (x)\ dx \rightarrow 2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Is it true or not?If it isn't then how can I find example?If it is true then please give me a hint.Then I will definitely retry it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explicit wether it is $f(x)^n$ or $f^{[n]}(x)$ the n-th iterate of $f$.

Comment: or is $f^n(x)$ really $f^{(n)}(x)$, the $n$-fold derivative of $f$?

Comment: Hint: Let $M = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in [0,1]\}$. Case 1: $M \leqslant 1$. Then it's easy to bound $\int_0^1 f(x)^n\,dx$ above to see it can't converge to $2$. Case 2: $M > 1$. Then bound the integral from below.

Comment: Do you mean @DanielFischer that the case where $M > 1$ and $m \leq 1$ then only the case may hold?

Answer (score 4):

Let  $A = \{x: \; f(x) > 1\}$.
If $A$ has positive measure, $$\int_0^1 f(x)^{n}\; dx \ge \int_A f(x)^{n}\; dx \to +\infty \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$
(using Monotone Convergence) so $A$ must have measure $0$.  But then $
\int_0^1 f(x)^n\; dx \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the power problem :

We have $\int_0^11dx=1$ so for the integral to be equal to $2$ then there must exist an $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)>1$ which is equivalent to $f(x_0)\ge1+\alpha$ with $\alpha>0$. (else $|f(x)^n|\le1$ and so is the integral).

Since $f$ is continuous $f(x)\ge1+\frac{\alpha}{2}$ for $x\in[a,b]$ for some $0\le a\lt x_0\lt b\le1$.

So $f(x)^n\ge(1+\frac{\alpha}{2})^n\ge \frac{\alpha}{2}n$ and $\int_0^1f(x)^ndx\ge\frac{(b-a)\alpha}{2}n\to+\infty$